# Square of Stars

Tags: c#

```
namespace SquareStars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i <n-1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*");

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My  exercises is to do Square of Stars  like this: 
depends of "n".I try to use for loops,but I can do right side of square.
I do this:

```
***
* 
***
```

but I want this:

```
***       ****
* *       *  *
***   or  *  *
          ****
```

Can sameone help me to this code????

Comment: You're actually very close to it, what prevents you to have it finished up.Note that you already have much more elegant solutions here under, especially the one from Psychosomatic, but yours is already close to an end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do:

```
public static string CreateASCIISquare(int squareSideLength, char c = '*')
{
    if (squareSideLength < 1)
        return "";

    if (squareSideLength == 1)
        return c.ToString();

    var horizontalOuterRow  = new String(c, squareSideLength);
    var horizontalInnerRow = $"{c}{new string(' ', squareSideLength - 2)}{c}";
    var squareBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    squareBuilder.AppendLine(horizontalOuterRow);

    for (int i = 0; i < squareSideLength - 2; i++)
    {
        squareBuilder.AppendLine(horizontalInnerRow);
    }

    squareBuilder.Append(horizontalOuterRow);
    return squareBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Ok, so lets explain the code a little bit:

1. Always validate the data going into your method. In your case the user can specify the length of the square's side. Are there any invalid values? Well clearly yes, `-2` doesn't seem to be a valid choice.

   You have many options here. You can tell the user the value is not valid, you can simply ignore it, do nothing and let your application crash and die miserably, or you can return an empty square. All are valid choices, but consciously choose one and design according to your decision. In my case I chose to return an empty square:

   ```
   if (squareSideLength < 0)
       return "";
   ```

   Are there any trivial cases I can manage easily without `for` loops and `Console.Write`s etc.? Yes, lengths `0` and `1` seem pretty straightforward. It stands to reason that if I've returned the empty square for negative values, I do the same for `0` sized squares. So I change the previous code to:

   ```
   if (squareSideLength < 1)
       return "";
   ```

   Good, now what about `1`? Well that's pretty easy too isn't it?

   ```
    if (squareSideLength == 1)
       return c.ToString();
   ```

   Moral of the story: take care of invalid data or trivial cases first. Many times trivial cases can also be corner cases that can complicate your general solution, get them out of the way fast!
2. Ok, now lets think about what a square looks like:

   ```
    **
    **

    ***
    * *
    ***

    ****
    *  *
    *  *
    ****
   ```

   Well the pattern seems pretty obvious. A square is made up of two rows containing the specified number of stars, and `0` or more rows containing only 2 stars and `squareSideLength  - 2` spaces in between. Well, its only two types of rows, lets build them up front:

   ```
    var horizontalOuterRow  = new String(c, squareSideLength);
    var horizontalInnerRow = $"{c}{new string(' ', squareSideLength - 2)}{c}";
   ```
3. Great! We got our building blocks, now lets build our square:

   So how does that go? Well we simply start by adding a `horizontalOuterRow` then we add the `squareSideLength - 2` `horizontalInnerRow`s and we finish up adding one more `horizontalOuterRow`.

   And voilá, we got ourselves our nice little ASCII square:

   ```
   squareBuilder.AppendLine(horizontalOuterRow);

   for (int i = 0; i < squareSideLength - 2; i++)
   {
       squareBuilder.AppendLine(horizontalInnerRow);
   }

   squareBuilder.Append(horizontalOuterRow);
   ```

   The fact that I've used a `StringBuilder` is not really germane to the question, but get into the habit of using this tool when constructing dynamically built strings you don't know the length of beforehand. Concatenating strings can give you pretty bad performance so it's best to avoid it if possible.
4. Now we proudly return our beautiful ASCII square back to our extatic user and bask under the general round of applause:

   ```
   return squareBuilder.ToString();
   ```

Hope this little answer helps you.

Remember, to code well, break everything up into very small tasks, and take care of them one at a time. Think how you'd do it by hand and write it that way. Once you have it working there'll be time to see if you need to optimize, refactor, etc. your code. But the key is getting it to work with code as clear as possible.

Comment: A bit overkill for such a simple problem, but still well presented, great explanations and usage of C# elements beside `for` loops. Well done

Comment: @GioraGuttsait Thanks ;) Yes its an overkill but the goal here is to convey good practices to someone who is clearly just learning how to code. The problem itself is just the means to do it. And I was bored...

Comment: Simpler: `var horizontalOuterRow = new String(c, squareSideLength);`

Comment: @HansKesting duh! Thanks, much nicer, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`string(char, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor to create strings of repeating characters. This lets you simplify the code to use a single `for` loop:

```
        var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', n)); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*" + new string(' ', n - 2) + "*");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', n));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++)
            {
                if (row == 1 || row == n)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (col == 1 || col == n)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Console.WriteLine` in 2nd loop like this :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i == 0 ? "*" : "*" + string.Empty.PadLeft(n - 2) + "*");

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }
}
```